# Combinatorics calculation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve a problem and stuck at an intermediate step. Let $s_M$ be average of elements of a set $M\subset N$, $|N|=n$. Find an average of all $s_M$.

I got result as :
(Sum of all set elements)*(1),where (1) is given below :
$$ \tag{1}
{n-1 \choose 0}/1+
{n-1 \choose 1}/2+
{n-1 \choose 2}/3+\ldots+
{n-1 \choose n-1}/n
$$
But given result is :

((sum of all set elements)$(2^n-1))/n$................(2)

I know C(n,0)+C(n,1)...C(n,n)=($2^n$).

(1) and (2) gives same result.But how can we go from (1) to (2)?

Comment: the answer given is clearly wrong!!

Comment: sorry for bad post.I have updated the question.

Comment: The question asks to find average of all subsets, may i ask what does the set contain? I take that given answer correct then, say size of set is one...then the sum of averages is 1? and not the element itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just find a closed form for your sum. Let $$f(x):= {n-1 \choose 0}x/1+
{n-1 \choose 1}x^2/2+
{n-1 \choose 2}x^3/3+\ldots+
{n-1 \choose n-1}x^{n}/n
$$
You need to find $f(1)$.
Then \begin{align} f'(x)&={n-1 \choose 0}+
{n-1 \choose 1}x+
{n-1 \choose 2}x^2+\ldots+
{n-1 \choose n-1}x^{n-1} \\
&= (1+x)^{n-1}
\end{align}

So \begin{align}f(x) &= \int (1+x)^{n-1}\,dx 
 = {(1+x)^{n}\over n}+c
\end{align}
Since $f(0)=0$ we have $c=-{1\over n}$

Now put $x=1$ and you are done: $f(1) = {2^{n}-1\over n}$

Comment: thanks for explanation